# Timer to show/ hide subview

Tags: ios, hide, show, subview

I am stuck in something I hope you guys can help

I have a scrollview , when the user scrolling a subview appear with animation from bottom to top. the timer then start counting 5 sec and then call another method to hide the subview

I implemented and it works as wanted except :
while the subview appear and when it's almost to hide , if I scrolled that moment the subview appear statically and never hide . try to scrolling again another subview dynamically work over the static one ( as it duplicated or something)

this is my code for controlling show and hide of subview

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(!show){


        [self showSubview];
          if (!myidleTimer)
        [self resetIdleTimer];

    }

}


-(void)resetIdleTimer
{


    //convert the wait period into minutes rather than seconds
    int timeout = kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes;// equal to 5 seconds
    [myidleTimer invalidate];
    myidleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)idleTimerExceeded
{

    if (show){
         [myidleTimer invalidate];
        [self hideSubview];
        show=false;

    }
}
```

"show" is a bool to insure when to hide and when to show
her is the show / hide implementation

```
  -(void)hideSubview{


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
     subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 60);//move it out of screen
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [subview removeFromSuperview];
                         subview.frame=CGRectMake(0,screenWidth, screenHeight, 0);
                     }];
        show=false;
}


-(void) showSubview{

    subview = [[UIView alloc] init ];

    [self.view addSubview:subview];
    subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 60);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenWidth-60, screenHeight, 60);
                     }];

        show=TRUE;

 }
```

I hope that's clear enough to understand and be able to help me identify the problem
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The timer will not fire while the scroll view is being scrolled, if you create the timer the way you do. Instead, create it as below.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(doStuff:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: adds the timer to the run loop using the defaultRunLoopMode instead of the NSRunLoopCommonModes, which is the one you want to have timer fire while the user scrolls.

Comment: but I don't want timer to start fire while I'm scrolling , I want it as checker if the scrolling stopped it'll count 5 seconds then disappear. and if user scroll the view again it will appear again